# Rendering "sketch-like" splines in Python?

Tags: python, graphics, rendering, sketching

How can I render "sketch-like" lines and splines in Python?  For example, I would like to give this graphviz specfication a hand-drawn appearance.

Any output method is fine, I will eventually generate an image file from the rendering.

```
% echo 'digraph G {a -> b -> c; a -> c}'|dot -Tplain
graph 1 1.125 2.5
node a 0.75 2.25 0.75 0.5 a solid ellipse black lightgrey
node b 0.375 1.25 0.75 0.5 b solid ellipse black lightgrey
node c 0.75 0.25 0.75 0.5 c solid ellipse black lightgrey
edge a b 4 0.65922 2.0008 0.61731 1.8921 0.56651 1.7604 0.51952 1.6386 solid black
edge a c 10 0.80075 1.9987 0.82883 1.8551 0.86084 1.6679 0.875 1.5 0.89367 1.2786 0.89367 1.2214 0.875 1 0.86538 0.88587 0.84751 0.76283 0.82823 0.65063 solid black
edge b c 4 0.46578 1.0008 0.50769 0.89209 0.55849 0.76039 0.60548 0.63857 solid black
stop
```